How do I eager load multiple associations in same query with ActiveRecord?
Given the following:

Project has_many collectors
Collector has_one gs_collector
GsCollector has_one model
Model has a field named title

How do I in one query get all the model titles inside any one Project without using map or something similar AND without getting the N + 1 problem?
By using map, I have various solutions that work, but they all query the database more than once:
Project.joins(collectors: { gs_collector: :model }).find(92666).collectors.map{ |coll| coll.gs_collector.model.title }


You have misunderstood what joins is used for. joins is not actually used to eager load records and solve the common n+1 problem. It's used to add a INNER JOIN clause that can be used to filter out rows with no match in the join table or to add conditions based on the join table. No columns in the joined table will be selected. For eager loading you eager_load, preload or includes. https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes

You can do something like this
Model.joins(gs_collector: :collector).where(collectors: { project_id: 92666 }).pluck(:title)
